# Firebase generated image file using php script upload

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, firebase, firebase-storage

In firebase example file upload using javascript and file we get using

```js
var f=event.target.files[0];
```

But I'm generating file runtime using php script and I want to upload that generated file in firebase server. I have file path. How can I do that? I'm using CodeIgniter Web Framework.

Comment: Can you please clarify the question? Are you looking for a JavaScript answer, or a PHP answer? Is this done client side, or is your PHP server handling this?

Comment: I'm uploading one image file to my php server than my php script create 4 thumb and I want to upload those 4 thumb files to firebase bucket and want to use firebase as cdn server. So everything handle by php.